# An algorithm for Random Number Pair Generation

Tags: php, algorithm, random

So I am looking for a program which generates a random pair of values from a given set of keys. The key idea here is to find the highest degree of divergence and minimal repeatability.

**Input:** Array of keys, systemtime() *//as most of the randomizing functions use system time as a parameter*
**Output:** The two keys that have to be returned to the calling function

**generatepair(arrayofkeys[], systemtime())**

The key requirement is minimal repeatability. Best case scenario would be wherein a pair generated once should not be generated again, unless such a combination is not possible.
Also, there is a global datastore consists of all previously generated pairs, and forbidden pair which cannot be ever generated. But data independence would be highly appreciated.

Additionally, I'll be coding in PHP if that information might be useful or constraining.

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried?

Comment: Well, not homework exactly. Working on a site which requires to pair up two numbers. Like an event such as throwing a dice. But thats a small number of combinations. The arrayofkeys is however a large dataset. I can generate the pairs and it is a simple thing. I am using the rand() function to do that. My only issue is to reduce the repeatability. Comparing with previously generated pairs is an option is a way, but then it just is a lot of operations for the algorithm. So I am looking for a different method.

Comment: I think you will find that if you give this problem a solid try, by either researching online or writing some code, you will get a much more useful response from StackOverflow. And certainly you won't lose any points. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well firstly, to achieve "best case" repeatability you could simply remove the pair of numbers form the arrayofkeys to avoid them repeating again.
And if you do not want that to happen, you're not really generating your numbers purely randomly.

To generate your numbers only within a specific range use rand(x,y) where x and y are your limits. You can get those from your arrayofkeys by doing min(arrayofkeys) and max(arrayofkeys).

Comment: But then in that case if all are keys pairs have been generated previously, then it will return null. It has to return a pair always. So maybe I'll assign weights to every pair, which keep incrementing everytime it is selected. And selected proceeds with finding the ones with minimum weight.

Comment: You do realize then that this is not fair randomness. If that is not an issue, you could do that.

Comment: Yeah, I guess. I think my primary concern is repeatability more than randomness so yeah! Thanks!